# Not able to add prod and test profiles in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When I create a new file and name is application-dev.properties, I am able to add configurations in there and then by using spring.profiles.active in default application.properties I am able to get dev profile configurations. But similarly if I create a test or a prod profile, it is not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJARc.png)

Comment: `it is not working` what is not working? Where do you expect those parameters to be?

Comment: you can set the profile to be used like `java -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=test `